# Floating point operations 32 bit mode vs 64 bit mode

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, floating-accuracy

I have the same number crunching source code in Delphi which is compiled both as 32 bit and as 64 bit application. From the log file I can see that the numbers are slightly (1e-14 relative error) different. So I'm wondering if it is possible that the same CPU performs floating point operations differently when running 32 bit and 64 bit code. Or is it something that the compiler is responsible for.

Comment: Relevant note: 64-bit programs and floating-point calculations - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0074/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the code does not explicitly use `Extended`. Since that data type differs between 32 and 64 bit (it's 10 bytes in 32 bit and 8 bytes in 64 bit), any explicit use of `Extended` introduces an immediate difference. I'm going to assume that you are using `Double` for all your variables. Although the arguments below transfer across equally to `Single`.

Beyond that, the most common reason for this is a difference in behaviour between the two floating point units.

The x87 unit, used by 32 bit code, stores intermediate values to 80 bit extended precision. The SSE unit, used by 64 bit code, stores intermediate values to 64 bit double precision.

Now, the x87 unit can be configured using the control word to store intermediate values to 64 bit precision. It makes no difference in terms of performance, but will align your 32 and 64 bit results to be closer.

Even then you won't get exactly the same results on the different units. In fact you won't get the exact same results on all x87 units. Even though these units are all IEEE754 conformant, that standard allows a degree of leeway for calculations.

What's more, higher order calculations like trigonometry, logarithms, exponentiation etc. are performed quite differently between 32 and 64 bit. The 32 bit unit has more built in functionality than the 64 bit unit. You'll note in the Delphi source code that the trig functions, for example, are all implemented in the RTL for 64 bit. On 32 bit code they are implemented by calling x87 ops.

The bottom line is that you will never get your 32 and 64 bit programs to agree exactly when there are floating point calculations involved. You will have to accept differences to a small tolerance.

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions: no explicit `Extended`, just `Doubles`. I wonder why CPU in 64 bit mode cannot use x87 unit. It seems that it is more accurate.

Comment: CPU in 64 bit code could use x87 unit. It's no more accurate though. And SSE FP is a lot faster than x87 FP. Recent trends have been to spend transistor budget on SSE unit at the expense of x87.

Comment: There is a library backporting some math capabilities using x87 FPU in 64 bit. [`TExtendedX87: FPU-backed 80-bit Extended type for Win64`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28488).

Comment: @LURD That's a very neat library. It's Extended only though so it won't help you run your Double precision maths on x87, not that that would be a good idea in my view. If I recall, that library declares the record as packed which I think is an error.

Comment: David, TExtendedX87 is a variant record, and I think the packed keyword is ok here in Win64. `TExtendedX87 = packed record
case byte of
0: (AsBytes: packed array [0..9] of byte);
1: (AsExtRec80: System.TExtended80Rec);
end;`.

Comment: @LURD The problem is that it gives the type an alignment of one which leads to it being misaligned. So memory performance is very badly affected. Note that `System.TExtended80Rec` is also mis-aligned for the same reason. I would add a dummy `Double` to the record, remove the `packed` and therefore arrange alignment of 8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The intention was for TExtendedX87 to have some compatibility with Delphi's internals (i.e. System.TExtended80Rec). Since this is a packed record, removing the "packed" from the declaration of TExtendedX87 wouldn't change anything. The "packed" there simply makes explicit. There would be the option to declare it "packed record .. end align 16", but (at least in XE2) this feature is pretty much broken and only of limited use.

Comment: David could you tell me should I be worried again about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521608/floating-point-number-conversion-horror-is-there-a-way-out) under 64bit? How do I steer rounding and other things under 64bit if there is no control word? Can different libraries mess with my calculations like it was on 32 bit?

Comment: @Wodzu It's just the same under x64, albeit on a different FPU (SSE rather than 8087). Instead of Set8087CW there is SetMXCSR. There are also generic functions that control rounding, exception masking etc. that have the same interface for 32 and 64 bit. In other words, you don't need to use any target specific code.

Answer (score 4):

`Extended` is equal to `Double` in X64. X32 mode is using the FPU floating point unit, while X64 is using the SSE registers for floating point execution.

There is also the compiler directive [`Floating point precision control (Delphi for x64)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Floating_point_precision_control_%28Delphi_for_x64%29), which by default is on and keeps intermediate single floats as doubles.