# Floating point number conversion horror, is there a way out?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, floating-point, type-conversion, delphi-2009

**Background**

Recently my colleague add some new tests to our test project. One of them has not passed on or continuous integration system. Since we have around 800 tests and it takes an hour to run all of it, we often make a mistake and run on our dev machines only the tests which we've currently implemented. This method has its weakness because from time to time tests are passing locally but then fail on the integration system. Of course, someone could say "it is not a mistake, tests should be independent of each other!".

In ideal world.. sure, but not in my world. Not in a world in which you have a lot of singletons initialized in `initialization` section, lot of global variables introduced by the Delphi itself, an OTL thread pool initialized in background, DevExpress methods hooked to your controls for painting purposes.. and dozens of other things which I am not aware of. So in final result one test can change the behavior of other test. (Which of course is bad itself and I am glad it happen, because hopefully I will be able to fix another dependency).

I've started the whole test package on my machine and I've achieved the same results as on integration system. So far so good, now I've started turning off tests until I've narrowed down the one test which interfered with the one recently added. They have nothing in common. I've digged deeper, and narrowed the problem to one single line. If I comment it - test passes, if not - test fails.

**Problem**

We have such code to convert text data into longitude coords(only important part was included):

```
procedure TTerminalNVCParserTest_Unit.TranslateGPS_ValidGPSString_ReturnsValidCoords;
const
  CStrGPS = 'N5145.37936E01511.8029';
var
  LLatitude, LLongitude: Integer;
  LLong: Double;
  LStrLong, LTmpStr: String;
  LFS: TFormatSettings;
begin
  FillChar(LFS, SizeOf(LFS), 0);
  LFS.DecimalSeparator := '.';

  LStrLong := Copy(CStrGPS, Pos('E', CStrGPS)+1, 10);
  LTmpStr := Copy(LStrLong,1,3);
  LLong := StrToFloatDef( LTmpStr, 0, LFS );
  LTmpStr := Copy(LStrLong,4,10);
  LLong := LLong + StrToFloatDef( LTmpStr, 0, LFS)*1/60;
  LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000);

  CheckEquals(1519671, LLongitude);
end;
```

The problem is that `LLongitude` is sometimes equal to 1519671 and sometimes it gives 1519672. And whether it gives 1519672 or not is dependent from other totally unrelated piece of code in different method in different test:

```
FormXtrMainImport.JvWizard1.SelectNextPage;
```

I've quadruple checked SelectNextPage method, it does not fire any event that could change how the FPU unit works. It does not change the value of `RoundingMode` it is always set up on rmNearest.

Besides, shouldn't Delphi use here a banker rule? :

```
LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000); //LLong * 100000 = 1519671,5
```

If banker rule is used it should give me always 1519672 not 1519671.

I guess that there must be some corrupted memory which is causing the problem and the line with `SelectNextPage` only reveals it. However the same problem occurs on three different machines.

Anyone could give me an idea how to trace this problem? Or how to assure always a stable result of conversion?

**To those who misunderstood my question**

1. I've checked the RoundingMode and I've mentioned about it earlier: *"I've quadruple checked SelectNextPage method, it does not fire any event that could change how the FPU unit works. It does not change the value of RoundingMode it is always set up on rmNearest."* **RoundingMode is always rmNearest before any runding occurs in the above code.**
2. This is not the real test. This is only the code to show where problem occurs.

**Video description added.**

So, in striving to improve my question I've decided to add the video that shows my bizzare problem. This is the production code, I've only added assertions for checking RoundingMode.
In first part of the video I am showing the original test (@Sir Rufo , @Craig Young), the method responsible for conversion and the correct result which I am getting. In the second part I am showing that when I add another unrelated test I am getting incorrect result. Video can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByKpG-WK821wRTVUQWJEdDZ3QjQ)

**Reproducible example added**

It all boils down to below code:

```
procedure FloatingPointNumberHorror;
const
  CStrGPS = 'N5145.37936E01511.8029';
var
  LLongitude: Integer;
  LFloatLon: Double;
  adcConnection: TADOConnection;
  qrySelect: TADOQuery;
  LCSVStringList: TStringList;
begin
  //Tested on Delphi 2007, 2009, XE 5 -  Windows 7 64 bit
  adcConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  qrySelect := TADOQuery.Create(adcConnection);
  LCSVStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //Prepare on the fly csv file required by ADOQuery
    LCSVStringList.Add('Col1;Col2;');
    LCSVStringList.Add('aaaa;1234;');
    LCSVStringList.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'test.csv');

    qrySelect.CursorType := ctStatic;
    qrySelect.Connection := adcConnection;
    adcConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='
      + ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + ';Extended Properties="text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(;)"';

    // Real stuff begins here, above we have only preparation of environment.
    LFloatLon := 15 + 11.8029*1/60;
    LLongitude := Round(LFloatLon * 100000);
    Assert(LLongitude = 1519671, 'Asertion 1'); //Here you will NOT receive error.

    //This line changes the FPU control word from $1372 to $1272.
    //This causes the change of Precision Control Field (PC) from 3 which means
    //64bit precision to 2 which means 53 bit precision thus resulting in improper rounding?
    //--> ADODB.TParameters.InternalRefresh->RefreshFromOleDB -> CommandPrepare.Prepare(0)
    qrySelect.SQL.Text := 'select * from [test.csv] WHERE 1=1';

    LFloatLon := 15 + 11.8029*1/60;
    LLongitude := Round(LFloatLon * 100000);
    Assert(LLongitude = 1519671, 'Asertion 2'); //Here you will receive error.

  finally
    adcConnection.Free;
    LCSVStringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Just copy and paste this procedure and add `ADODB` to uses clause. It seems that the problem is caused by some Microsoft COM object which is used by Delphi's ADO wrapper. This object is changing FPU control word, but it is **not changing the rounding mode.** It is changing precision control.

Here is the FPU screenshot before and after firing up ADO-related method.:

[image: FPU screenshot]

The only solution which comes to my mind is to use `Get8087CW` before using ADO code and then `Set8087CW` to setup control world with previously stored one.

Comment: Which result do you get if you leave the controlling line in, but do not run the test containing it?

Comment: To me you get the unit test wrong. I would expect to see something like `CheckEquals( 1519671, ConvertGPS( CStrGPS ).Longitude );`. You have to test functions and not a bunch of code, you also implement somewhere else.

Comment: Check the rounding mode in your test to be sure, like `Assert(Math.GetRoundMode = rmNearest);`

Comment: To reiterate what @SirRufo says. Your test is wrong. You're not testing your production code at all. If you change (break) your production code, your test will still pass.

Comment: See also [`What can change my floating point control word behind my back?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7687673/576719).

Comment: @LURD I have never got to the bottom of that one. It's still a total mystery to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is most likely because something else in your code is changing the floating point rounding mode. Have a look at this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

const
  CStrGPS = 'N5145.37936E01511.8029';
var
  LLatitude, LLongitude: Integer;
  LLong: Double;
  LStrLong, LTmpStr: String;
  LFS: TFormatSettings;

begin
  FillChar(LFS, SizeOf(LFS), 0);
  LFS.DecimalSeparator := '.';

  LStrLong := Copy(CStrGPS, Pos('E', CStrGPS)+1, 10);
  LTmpStr := Copy(LStrLong,1,3);
  LLong := StrToFloatDef( LTmpStr, 0, LFS );
  LTmpStr := Copy(LStrLong,4,10);
  LLong := LLong + StrToFloatDef( LTmpStr, 0, LFS)*1/60;

  Writeln(FloatToStr(LLong));
  Writeln(FloatToStr(LLong*100000));

  SetRoundMode(rmNearest);
  LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000);
  Writeln(LLongitude);

  SetRoundMode(rmDown);
  LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000);
  Writeln(LLongitude);

  SetRoundMode(rmUp);
  LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000);
  Writeln(LLongitude);

  SetRoundMode(rmTruncate);
  LLongitude := Round(LLong * 100000);
  Writeln(LLongitude);

  Readln;
end.
```

The output is:

```
15.196715
1519671.5
1519671
1519671
1519672
1519671
```

Clearly your particular calculation depends on the floating point rounding mode as well as the actual input value and the code. Indeed the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Round) does make this point:

> **Note**: The behavior of Round can be affected by the Set8087CW procedure or System.Math.SetRoundMode function.

So you need to first of all find whatever else in your program is modifying the floating point control word. And then you must make sure that you set it back to the desired value whenever that mis-behaving code executes.

---

Congratulations on debugging this further. In fact it is actually the multiplication

```
LLong*100000
```

which is influenced by the precision control.

To see that this is so, look at this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  d: Double;
  e1, e2: Extended;
begin
  d := 15.196715;
  Set8087CW($1272);
  e1 := d * 100000;
  Set8087CW($1372);
  e2 := d * 100000;
  Writeln(e1=e2);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
FALSE
```

So, precision control influences the results of the multiplication, at least in the 80 bit registers of the 8087 unit.

The compiler doesn't store the result of that multiplication to a variable and it remains in the FPU, so this difference flows on to the `Round`.

```
Project1.dpr.9: Writeln(Round(LLong*100000));
004060E8 DD05A0AB4000     fld qword ptr [$0040aba0]
004060EE D80D84614000     fmul dword ptr [$00406184]
004060F4 E8BBCDFFFF       call @ROUND
004060F9 52               push edx
004060FA 50               push eax
004060FB A1107A4000       mov eax,[$00407a10]
00406100 E827F0FFFF       call @Write0Int64
00406105 E87ADEFFFF       call @WriteLn
0040610A E851CCFFFF       call @_IOTest
```

Notice how the result of the multiplication is left in `ST(0)` because that's exactly where `Round` expects its parameter.

In fact, if you pull the multiplication into a separate statement, and assign it to a variable, then the behaviour becomes consistent again:

```
tmp := LLong*100000;
LLongitude := Round(tmp);
```

The above code produces the same output for both `$1272` and `$1372`.

There basic issue remains though. You have lost control of the floating point control state. To deal with this you'll need to keep control of your FP control state. Whenever you call into a library that may modify it, store it away before calling, and then restore when the call returns. If you want to have anything like repeatable, reliable and robust floating point code, this sort of game is, unfortunately, inevitable.

Here is my code to do that:

```
type
  TFPControlState = record
    _8087CW: Word;
    MXCSR: UInt32;
  end;

function GetFPControlState: TFPControlState;
begin
  Result._8087CW := Get8087CW;
  Result.MXCSR := GetMXCSR;
end;

procedure RestoreFPControlState(const State: TFPControlState);
begin
  Set8087CW(State._8087CW);
  SetMXCSR(State.MXCSR);
end;

var
  FPControlState: TFPControlState;
....
FPControlState := GetFPControlState;
try
  // call into external library that changes FP control state
finally
  RestoreFPControlState(FPControlState);
end;
```

Note that this code handles both floating point units and so is ready for 64-bit which uses the SSE unit rather than the 8087 unit.

---

For what it is worth, here is my SSCCE:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  d: Double;
begin
  d := 15.196715;
  Set8087CW($1272);
  Writeln(Round(d * 100000));
  Set8087CW($1372);
  Writeln(Round(d * 100000));
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
1519672
1519671
```

Comment: I wrote that I've checked RoundingMode, quote: **"I've quadruple checked SelectNextPage method, it does not fire any event that could change how the FPU unit works. It does not change the value of RoundingMode it is always set up on rmNearest. "** This place is insane, and five people gave you +1. Noone even cared to fully read my question?:)

Comment: @Wodzu There is no other explanation for what you describe. Thanks for the downvote though. I guess you should boil your problem down to an SSCCE.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because I wrote that I've checked the RoundingMode and your answer says to me that I should check the RoundigMode :) Also, does not seem to you strange that Round(1519671.5) with rmNearest gives you 1519671? According to the [documentation](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Round) it should give you 1519672. I've wrote about it too and you've ignored that fact. Some times it is hard to get SSCCE especially when problem is hard and convoluted and you are not a native speaker, but your answer is far from perfect too...

Comment: Just so you know, I've spent 16 hours tracing this problem before I've decided to post my question. If I can somehow improve it, I will be glad to do that.

Comment: Delphi's documentation of the effects of rounding mode is bogus. But that's what influences the Round function's behaviour. My code shows that. Producing SSCCE here is hard, but do you want to solve the problem or not? Without a clean SSCCE you cannot solve the problem.

Comment: FWIW floating point control word can be hard to maintain control over. In my day job, I do a lot of floating point work, and I mean a lot, and it's critical that our code is robust and reliable and repeatable. There are many flaws in Delphi control word handling. I suggest you peruse this: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107411 to see how easy it is for you to lose control over your control word.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that link. In the meantime, could you check my edited question? I've added video describing the problem. I do not have any reasonable explanation of what is happening here...

Comment: I'm no longer terribly motivated given your actions. I'll help more when there's an SSCCE.

Comment: This particular problem can not be more clear and easy to understand than it is on a movie. Thanks for trying to help me anyway. Unfortunately in your QC an attachement is missing.

Comment: The attachment is there but I think you need to use the desktop QC client to get it. I'll wait until you post the SSCCE code here. At the very least show the FPU debug window with the FPU control word. Since `1519671.5` is exactly representable it should be a nice easy SSCCE.

Comment: Remember that `Round` is nothing more than a call to `FISTP` so it could not be a cleaner SSCCE. You need to capture the FPU control word and that should be it. Also try to get the 8 bytes of the floating point value `LLong`. With that it should be a 10 line SSCCE. And then we can get to work.

Comment: It was not possible to create SSCCE with 10 lines of code but I've managed to create a fully reproducible example. Just please, read it before you tell me to use Set8087CW() ;-)

Comment: That confirms what I have been telling you all along! FWIW, in my code I have a routine that stores the FPCW before calling an external library that modifies it. Then when that library returns, I restore the FPCW.

Comment: Ok, but are you able to reproduce that behaviour on your machine, could you confirm that? BTW: I've just read your article (had to run windows QC client for this), fascinating stuff! Unfortunately due to this attachement problem in web browser, probably not many people had read it. I would give you +100 for this article! :) I am gonna report my problem in QC and relate it to your solution.

Comment: There's little point in my view reporting this issue to QC. It's a known issue and Delphi is behaving as designed. It's basically down to you to keep control of your CW. You might wish to re-consider the downvote now by the way! ;-)

Comment: Yes I reproduce it. In fact read down to the bottom of my latest update to see an 11 line SSCCE. I think I have a full and complete analysis now.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, but I find your SSCCE somewhat unfair ;-) Anyway, I had no idea about this stuff and as you said I can not blame Delphi for this since it is the external code that is messing with FPCW. I've reconsidered my downvote :)

Comment: What do you mean about the SSCCE being unfair?

Comment: I mean, you are reproducing the problem by causing it with explict control of FPCW. You've simulated the same thing with less code but your example is missing an important information, which is that some external code might change FPCW. No matter as obvious that sounds I would not figured it out by looking at your SSCCE.

Comment: @Wodzu But that's what SSCCE is all about. You do need some knowledge to create them. Key knowledge here is that floating point results depend on both input and control word. Hence variation must be down to either input value or control word. So your debugging then looks for those variations. My SSCCE is to prove that my analysis is accurate. Anyway, do you still need more from me?

Comment: Yeah, I am not visiting this site to often, have forgotten about marking it as solved.