# Python 2.7 - How to access and control the Floating Point Control Word

Tags: python, dll, com

I am using Python 2.7 to control OpenDSS, a power simulation software, through a COM DLL. I am running into issues that appear to be related to the Floating Point Control Word being over-ridden by the COM DLL interface.

I can execute the solve of a circuit within the stand-alone version of OpenDSS, but when attempting to do so through the COM DLL, the precision with which the solve executes is lost.

I am using the Dispatch function under the win32com.client as follows:
self.dss = Dispatch("OpenDSSEngine.DSS")

After establishing the connection OpenDSS has some built-in functionality toward accessing it at different levels - 
self.dss.Text, self.dss.ActiveCircuit, self.dss.ActiveCircuit.ActiveCktElement, self.dss.ActiveCircuit.Solution

The given circuit is then loaded into the software and compiled using:
self.dss.Text.Command = r"Compile ' " + circuit_path + circuit_file

**Note that this initial compile appears to solve correctly

Error then arises using subsequent solve commands after making any changes to the circuit via:
self.dss.ActiveCircuit.Solution.Solve()

The creator of OpenDSS remarked to inquiry that a similar issue with the FPCW occurred with using MATLAB to control the software. It is evident based upon switches with very small resistance values producing very high currents that are inaccurate. What this seems to mean is that a voltage value is being divided by the very small resistance value and due to the lack of precision in FPCW, the software thinks that it has arrived at an acceptable solution even though resultant currents are inaccurate.

How can I access what the value of the FPCW is within Python? And how can I control it so that I achieve the required precision?

*Edit:

I have found the following thread discussing a similar issue in Delphi - 
[Floating point number conversion horror, is there a way out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521608/floating-point-number-conversion-horror-is-there-a-way-out?lq=1)

Does anybody know what the Python equivalent of the Set8087CW() function is?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Without seeing code it is difficult to guess what is going wrong here.  My best guess is that the Python/C++ interface is wrong in describing a double as a float, or maybe a double as an int.  If using `ctypes`, check the types again.  How are you calling the DLL?  Are you using the right calling convention?

Comment: I have elaborated above

Comment: I still can't see how you get your floating-point number back into python from the COM DLL.  What type does your function return and how is it converted to a python object?  For some background on Python floating point, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.

Comment: It is not a specific number that I'm after, the Solve() function referenced solves the model of the electrical circuit loaded into the software through the previous compile command. In this manner, I can change conditions in the electrical circuit, run Solve() and then through the built-in functionality access the updated properties of the electrical circuit. The problem is that the Solve() command is not solving the circuit with the same precision that the stand-alone version of the OpenDSS.exe program does. This is due to the FPCW being changed through the COM interface.

Comment: How do you know that part of the floating point number (the FPCW as you call it) is being changed?  It seems more likely that precision is being lost during a conversion, for example from double to float or double to text string, or between C++ and Python.